# How to handle a 'signed in' versus a 'default' homepage in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I am building a brand new website in Sitecore and I am looking for advice on the following scenario:

My site has 2 version of its homepage. Both are quite different. The layout is the same, but most of the components and sublayouts on it will change depending on whether the user is logged in or not.

Does anybody has a suggestion of a good practice, or way to do that in Sitecore? My basic requirements are, have a single URL for both (the website root, it is a homepage) and do not harm the content author experience.

My thought so far was:

- Use of personalization to control the components to be displayed (Concerns: performance and the content author experience he woudnt have to change component by component to see both versions)
- Use of two item in the tree and intercept a pipeline to resolve the right item at the right time (Concerns: the content author would have two home items to maintain *not actually a big problem)

Does anybody has any other approach or considerations on those I listed?

Thanks

Comment: As your 2nd page is for logged in user, its best to create a new page item and assign appropriate security permissions. Also, keep the personalization and security separate as they two different aspect.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution would be to make use of devices, and use a pipeline to switch devices if the user is logged in.

Set up your Device in Sitecore to use the default layout as a fallback so it does not affect other pages in your site (and they continue to work as expected). You are then able to set different sublayouts and components for that Item (directly or in Standard Values for the template) for each device. You can make use the VaryByDevice caching option to make better use of the Cache.

Your content editors can also switch between the devices easily in the Page Editor from the ribbon. Any further customization you need in other areas of the site, such has switching out a single component, can be run using a Personlization Rule taking advantage of `"where the current device compares to value"`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I think that is a good idea and makes a lot of sense, since what changes between the views are renderings. I am a bit concerned yet because of semantic. Anyway I will create o PoC using the approach you indicated.. thank you !

Comment: yes, I agree the sematics becomes a little broken. Not sure I would recommend this for a multisite approach either where a different device is used per site. The recommendation for Experience Explorer sounds like a good one, which follows "normal" practice...

Answer (score 1):

It does sound like you have the need for personalization based on authenticated status, so I would recommend staying with the built-in personalization interface to avoid confusion. Authors will have been trained during Sitecore training on how to use personalization, and introducing an alternative method for accomplishing the same thing could lead to a less-than-optimal experience for the author.

To address your concern of the author needing to view components by toggling each one, I would recommend installing the Experience Explorer module. You can create presets that meet your rules on your presentation and then the author can preview the site for different 'experiences'.

If you have a single URL for the home page, it is more straight-forward to go with a single item, so I would definitely advise against having two home page items that are being resolved by the same URL.

You mentioned a concern for performance, so I would recommend you making sure that you enable your sublayout caching settings. In your case, varying by Data may be the way to go, given you would personalize with two sets of datasources.

Comment: Hi Jay.. this was my first consideration, the problem I still see with that is that the page will change a lot of components and also some fixed sublayouts. I will also install the Experience Explorer module to check how that improves the content editor experience on page editor. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have used the following crude technique:

Make two components, one for "logged in" and the other for anonymous.

Each rendering has just one line, a single placeholder, either:

```
<sc:placeholder key="logged-in" runat="server" />
```

or

```
<sc:placeholder key="anonymous" runat="server" />
```

For "logged in" I make a personalisation rule which hides the component if anonymous, and for the anonymous component I make a personalisation rule which hides the component if the user is logged in.

I then nest all the components under the correct placeholder key.